# Area of a parallelogram using similar triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and point $M$ lies on $AB$ such that $AM:MB=2:3$. If $DM \cap AC=N$ and the area of $\triangle ADN=a$, I should find the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$.
> [image]

Let $AD=BC=b$ and $NN_1\perp AD=h_1, BB_1 \perp AD = h_2$. We have $S_{\triangle ADN}=\dfrac{AD.NN_1}{2}=\dfrac{b.h_1}{2}$ and $S_{ABCD}=AD.BB_1=b.h_2$. This is my idea but I can't approach the problem further. Maybe we can try to find $\dfrac{h_1}{h_2}$. Can you give a hint on how to continue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{S_{\Delta AMN}}{a}=\frac{NM}{DN}=\frac{AM}{DC}=\frac{2}{5}.$$
Thus, $$S_{\Delta ADM}=S_{\Delta ADN}+S_{\Delta AMN}=a+\frac{2}{5}a=\frac{7}{5}a.$$ Now, $$\frac{S_{\Delta ADB}}{S_{\Delta ADM}}=\frac{AB}{AM}=\frac{5}{2},$$ which gives 
$$S_{ABCD}=2S_{\Delta ADB}=2\cdot\frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{7}{5}a=7a.$$

Comment: A nice solution! Thank you! Do you see a way to finish what I've started?

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova I saw it, but I don't see how to finish.

Comment: What is the relationship between $S_{\triangle ADM}$ and $S_{\triangle ADB}$? How do we find it?

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova I found before $S_{\Delta ADM}.$ Is it clear? If so, $S_{\Delta ADB}=\frac{5}{2}S_{\Delta ADM}.$

Comment: I don't think you have written how you found $S_{\triangle{ADM}}$.

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova I added something. See now.

Comment: I am not asking about the area of $ADM$. I see this. I am asking about the relationship between the area of $ADM$ and $ADB$.

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova I added again. See now.

Comment: Nice solution! Well done! Thank you! I will think about my idea. If you see something, I would be very grateful if you share it with me.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova you can check out my updated alternate solution as well :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, thank you! I got it. I would like to ask you something if it's possible in a chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\Delta ANM$ is similar to $\Delta DNC$, so we need to find the area of $\Delta DNC$ in terms of $a$.

Let $Area(ABCD) = A$

$$Area(AND) + Area(CND) = \dfrac{A}{2}$$

$$\frac{Area(ANM)}{Area(CND)} = \bigg(\frac{AM}{CD}\bigg)^2 = \bigg(\frac{2}{5}\bigg)^2 = \frac{4}{25}$$

Also, 
$$Area(AND) + Area(ANM) = \dfrac{A}{5}$$

So, assuming $Area(CND) = x$, 
$$\therefore a + x = \frac{A}{2} \text{ and } a + \frac{4}{25}x = \frac{A}{5}$$

Now you can easily find both $a$ and $x$ in terms of $A$.
($a = \frac{A}{7}$ and $x = \frac{5}{14}A$)

Also, to answer your original question, yes you can find $\dfrac{h_1}{h_2}$, but in the end, it boils down to finding some similarity relations.